# jquery- button to remove all options from one selection and add to another selection

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following

```
<div class="container-fluid" style="padding-left:32px">
      <div class=container-fluid>
        <select id="leftValues" size="10" multiple>
            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
            <option>3</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="container-fluid center">
        <input type="button" id="btnLeft" value="&lt;&lt;" />
        <input type="button" id="btnRight" value="&gt;&gt;" />
    </div>
    <div class='container-fluid'>
        <select id="rightValues" size="10" multiple></select>
    </div>
</div>

<script language='javascript'>
$("#btnLeft").click(function() {
var values = $("#rightValues>option").map(function() { return $(this).val(); });
$.each(values, function(key, value) {   
     $('#leftValues')
         .append($("<option></option>")
                    .attr("value",key)
                    .text(value));
});

 $('#rightValues').html('');
});

$("#btnRight").click(function() {
var values = $("#leftValues>option").map(function() { return $(this).val(); });
$.each(values, function(key, value) {   
     $('#rightValues')
         .append($("<option></option>")
                    .attr("value",key)
                    .text(value));
});

 $('#leftValues').html('');
});
</script>
```

This is currently functional but seems like a terribly inefficient way to remove all options from one selection to move them to other. Is there an easier way to do this in Jquery (perhaps pure JS)?

### Edit

From the solution from karin:

```
$("#btnLeft").click(function() {
        $('#leftValues').html($('#rightValues').html());
        $('#rightValues').html('');
    });

$("#btnRight").click(function() {
    $('#rightValues').html($('#leftValues').html());
    $('#leftValues').html('');
 });

$("#rightValues").dblclick(function() {
    var selectedItem = $("#rightValues option:selected");
    $("#leftValues").append(selectedItem);
});

$("#leftValues").dblclick(function() {
    var selectedItem = $("#leftValues option:selected");
    $("#rightValues").append(selectedItem);
});
```

The problem is, I initially left out the dblclick event. If I have double clicked one thing to the right column and then use the arrow button to get it back over to the left list, it will replace the contents when I need it to add to the contents.

Comment: Why not just have a single `select` and move it around entirely?

Comment: Sorry, part of the code is not shown where you can select individual elements in the select as well. I want the columns to be independent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Small note: The code provided in the question actually doesn't work quite correctly...it transfers the indexes instead of the values of the column ;)

You can simplify your JS in this case to:

```
  $("#btnLeft").click(function() {
    $('#leftValues').html($('#rightValues').html());
    $('#rightValues').html('');
  });

  $("#btnRight").click(function() {
    $('#rightValues').html($('#leftValues').html());
    $('#leftValues').html('');
  });
```

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6e1w26n8/) with that code in play.

**EDIT**:

To get the behavior the updated question asks for:

```
  $("#btnLeft").click(function() {
    var items = $("#rightValues option");
    $('#leftValues').append(items);
  });

  $("#btnRight").click(function() {
    var items = $("#leftValues option");
    $('#rightValues').append(items);
  });

  $("#rightValues").dblclick(function() {
    var selectedItem = $("#rightValues option:selected");
    $("#leftValues").append(selectedItem);
  });

  $("#leftValues").dblclick(function() {
    var selectedItem = $("#leftValues option:selected");
    $("#rightValues").append(selectedItem);
  });
```

Here's an updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6e1w26n8/2/).

Answer (score 1):

You can set `data-*` attributes at `<input type="button">` elements referencing `<select>` to retrieve `option` elements from, `.siblings()`, `.data()`, `.appendTo()`

html

```
<input type="button" id="btnLeft" value="&lt;&lt;"
       data-toggle="#rightValues" />
<input type="button" id="btnRight" value="&gt;&gt;" 
       data-toggle="#leftValues"/>
```

javascript

```
$("[id^=btn]").click(function(e) {
  $($(this).data("toggle") + " option")
  .appendTo($(this).siblings().data("toggle"))
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid" style="padding-left:32px">
  <div class=container-fluid>
    <select id="leftValues" size="10" multiple>
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
      <option>3</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="container-fluid center">
    <input type="button" id="btnLeft" data-toggle="#rightValues" value="&lt;&lt;" />
    <input type="button" id="btnRight" data-toggle="#leftValues" value="&gt;&gt;" />
  </div>
  <div class='container-fluid'>
    <select id="rightValues" size="10" multiple></select>
  </div>
</div>
<script language='javascript'>
  $("[id^=btn]").click(function(e) {
    $($(this).data("toggle") + " option").appendTo($(this).siblings().data("toggle"))
  });
</script>
```